# How to open the Low Disk Space window again because qBittorent doesn't let me save files to another HDD

Tags: partitioning, disk-usage, qbittorrent

I tried to find something to open this window, but nothing worked. How can I open this window again? How can I move programs/files to another volume? I selected do not show again, and I know that I can extend the partition that has only 722.6 MB disk space remaining with GParted, but I want to move the files. When I use qBittorent it doesn't let me save or move the files to another hard drive. How can I do it?

[image: Error window]

Comment: If you want a useful answer, please try to limit your Question to a single question. Also try the 'Search' feature - how to move files from one partition to another is a long-answered question. Changing your torrent client's settings depends, of course, upon which torrent client you are using.

Comment: @user535733 also my other pc was full that error window open the disk usage analyzer. Do you know any good answered question about move files from one partition to another? And i wrote which client i'm using but i forgot the q that now i will add. However bittorent without the q is also a client. I didn' t write only torrent.

Comment: With this guide you can move the home partition to another hard disk https://help.ubuntu.com/community/Partitioning/Home/Moving#Setup_Partitions only at some point it required me to use ctrl+alt+f1 because although the home partition was mounted and so i cannot perform a command.  In the guide that was missing.